# MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail returns null

Tags: android, kotlin, thumbnails

In my app, one of my activities have a menu options that opens up gallery intent and allows user to pick an image. Inside onActivityResult, I call  MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail to retrieve thumbnail version of the selected image. However, it returns null for some reason. I have dynamic user permission set up for read/write access to external storage, and I think it's working (Otherwise, Android would issue security exception). Here's an excerpt of my code :

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, responseData: Intent?) {
    when (requestCode) {
        MENU_PICK_IMAGE -> if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            responseData?.let{ data  ->
                val contentUri = data.data as Uri
                val uriPath = contentUri.pathSegments
                val imageId = uriPath.get(uriPath.size-1)

                val b = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(contentResolver,imageId.toLong(),MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,null)
                ........
            }

        }
}
```

Target SDK : 28
compileSdkVersion 28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my issue by moving getThumbnail method to another method (outside of OnActivityResult). My assumption is that getThumbnail is blocked from accessing the data right after an image is selected by user (hence returning just null).